# Receiving "Unable to Connect to the File" error when I try to upload Tableau workbook to server

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I am trying to upload a Tableau workbook to the Tableau server

I am getting the following message

[image]

The path to the data source seems fine - when I enter the path into the browser window, I am able to connect to it and it downloads the file without issues

"C:/Users/cmomah/Documents/Projects/Analytics Database/Voucher Statistics Dashboard/Troubleshooting/VoucherStatsDashboard.twb Files/Data/Analytics Dashboard/vchr_cnt_hr.xlsx"

Does anyone have any clue where this error is coming from and how I might be able to resolve it and upload to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must use a UNC path when referencing a file-based data source. The Excel file is on the local C: drive; how is the server supposed to get to that file? It doesn't have any knowledge of your C: drive.

Here's a blog that details the process for handling file-based data sources:

https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2020/06/auto-refresh.html

Source of the correct answers:
[Getting error when trying to upload a Tableau workbook to the tableau server](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D74T000001YQGq/detail?s1oid=00D4T000000Dj8G&s1nid=0DB4T000000GnPK&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0054T000001wr2w&emtm=1613861027945&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0)